# Cout stops printing after a few lines (c++)

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, freeze, cout

I am writing this program for my class and have run into an issue. There are no errors but when I try to compile (compiling with g++), the program stops outputting to console after the line "Stuart placing order.\n". I know \n doesn't flush the output, so I tried using flush but that didn't work (maybe I did it wrong?). What do I need to do to allow the program to show the full output in console? I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong as I've been trying to figure out the problem for a while now. I'm still relatively new so I apologize if this is a simple fix. Thank you in advance.

**output:**

```
Kevin placing order.
Invalid input [Iron Goddess].
Not serving requested drinks. Drink order ignored.
Order Detail:
        Kevin
        Date: 3/2/2021
        Phone: 123-456-0000
        Total Balance: $21.75
        Ordered Drinks: 4
Balance: $39.279
Discounted Balance: $37.315

Stuart placing order.
```

**main**

```
#include <string>
#include "Order.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const Account Stuart("Stuart", "Owner");
    
    Account Kevin("Kevin", "VIP");

    Account Bob("Bob", "");

    cout << "Kevin placing order.\n";
    BobaOrder K("Kevin", 3, 2, 2021, "123-456-0000", 10.4, "Bar Pa Tea", 0.0);
    try
    {
        K.addDrink("Matcha Lemonade", 1, true);
        K.addDrink("Lemon Green Tea", 1, false);
        K.addDrink("Brown Sugar Oolong Tea", 2, false);
        K.addDrink("Iron Goddess", 1, false);
    }
    catch(InvalidInput& WrongDrink)
    {
        WrongDrink.cause();
        cout << "Not serving requested drinks. Drink order ignored.\n";
    }

    cout.precision(5);
    K.printReceipt();
    cout << "Balance: $" << K.calcBalance() << endl;
    cout << "Discounted Balance: $"  << applyDiscount(&K, &Kevin) << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Stuart placing order.\n";
    FoodOrder S("Stuart", 3, 2, 2021, "123-456-1111", 25.5, "Trauts Steak House", 0.0);
    try
    {
        S.addFood("Bone-in Ribeye", 2, true);
        S.addFood("Grilled Salmon", 1, false);
        S.addFood("Beyond Meat Burger", 3, true);
    }
    catch(InvalidInput& WrongFood)
    {
        WrongFood.cause();
        cout << "Not serving requested food. Food order ignored.\n";
    }

    S.printReceipt();
    cout << "Balance: $" << S.calcBalance() << endl;
    cout << "Discounted Balance: $"  << applyDiscount(&S, &Stuart) << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**cpp file**

```
#include "Order.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int DeliveryOrder::orderCount;
const float DeliveryOrder::taxRate = 0.0887;
const float DeliveryOrder::deliveryRate = 1.5;
int BobaOrder::drinksCount;
int FoodOrder::foodCount;

DeliveryOrder::DeliveryOrder(string name, int month, int day, int year, string phone, float miles, float balance = 0.0)
{
    DeliveryOrder::name = name;
    DeliveryOrder::month = month;
    DeliveryOrder::day = day;
    DeliveryOrder::year = year;
    DeliveryOrder::phone = phone;
    DeliveryOrder::miles = miles;
    DeliveryOrder::balance = balance;
    orderCount++;
}

DeliveryOrder::~DeliveryOrder()
{
    cout << "DeliveryOrder destroyed.\n";
}

void DeliveryOrder::printReceipt() const
{
    cout << "Order Detail:" << "\n";
    cout << "\t" << name << "\n";
    cout << "\tDate: " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << "\n";
    cout << "\tPhone: " << phone << "\n";
    cout << "\tTotal Balance: $" << balance << "\n";
}

float DeliveryOrder::calcBalance() 
{
    balance = balance * (1 + taxRate) + miles * deliveryRate;
    return balance;
}

float DeliveryOrder::getBalance() const
{
    return balance;
}

int DeliveryOrder::getOrderCount()
{
    return orderCount;
}

BobaOrder::BobaOrder(string name, int month, int day, int year, string phone, float miles, string shopName, float balance)
            :DeliveryOrder(name, month, day, year, phone, miles, balance)
{
    BobaOrder::shopName = shopName;
}

BobaOrder::~BobaOrder()
{
    cout << "BobaOrder destroyed.\n";
}

void BobaOrder::printReceipt() const
{
    DeliveryOrder::printReceipt();
    cout << "\tOrdered Drinks: " << drinksCount << endl;
}

float BobaOrder::VIPdiscount() const
{
    float discount;
    if (drinksCount > 10){discount = 0.85;}
    else
    {
        if (drinksCount > 5){discount = 0.9;}
        else
        {
            if (drinksCount > 2){discount = 0.95;}
            else
            {
                if(drinksCount <= 2){discount = 1;}
            }
        }
    }
    return discount;
}

void BobaOrder::addDrink(string drinkName, int sameDrink = 1, bool boba=true) 
{
   
   
    if (drinkName == "Matcha Lemonade"){balance = balance + 5.5 * sameDrink;}
    else 
    {   
        if (drinkName == "Brown Sugar Oolong Tea"){balance = balance + 5 * sameDrink;}
        else 
        {
            if (drinkName == "Lemon Green Tea"){balance = balance + 5.25 * sameDrink;}
            else
            {
                throw InvalidInput(drinkName);
            }
        }       
    }
    if (boba==true){balance = balance + 1 * sameDrink;}
    drinksCount = drinksCount + sameDrink;
}

FoodOrder::FoodOrder(string name, int month, int day, int year, string phone, float miles, string restaurantName, float balance)
            :DeliveryOrder(name, month, day, year, phone, miles, balance)
{
    FoodOrder::restaurantName = restaurantName;
}

FoodOrder::~FoodOrder()
{
    cout << "FoodOrder destroyed.\n";
}

void FoodOrder::printReceipt() const
{
    FoodOrder::printReceipt();
    cout << "\tOrdered Foods: " << foodCount << endl;
}

float FoodOrder::VIPdiscount() const
{
    float discount;
    if (balance > 50){discount = 0.85;}
    else
    {
        if (balance > 30){discount = 0.9;}
        else
        {
            if (balance > 20){discount = 0.95;}
            else
            {
                if(balance <= 20){discount = 1;}
            }
        }
    }
    return discount;
}

void FoodOrder::addFood(string foodName, int sides = 0, bool soup=false)
{  
    if (foodName == "Bone-in Ribeye"){balance = 32 + balance;}
    else
    {
        if (foodName == "Rack of Lamb"){balance = 28 + balance;}
        else
        {
            if (foodName == "Grilled Salmon"){balance = 24 + balance;}
            else 
            {
                if (foodName == "Beyond Meat Burger"){balance = 22 + balance;}
                else
                {
                    throw InvalidInput(foodName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (soup==true){balance = balance + 0.5;}
    balance = balance + sides * 1;
    foodCount++;
}

Account::Account(string username, string status)
{
    Account::username = username;
    Account::status = status;
}

Account::~Account()
{
    cout << "Account Removed.\n";
}

string Account::getStatus() const
{
    return status;
}

float applyDiscount(DeliveryOrder *o, Account const *a)
{
    float b = o->getBalance();
    float v = o->VIPdiscount();
    if (a->getStatus() == "Owner"){b = b * 0.1;}
    else
    {
        if(a->getStatus() == "VIP"){b = b * v;}
    }
    return b;
}
```

**h file**

```
#ifndef ORDER_H
#define ORDER_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DeliveryOrder
{
    private:
        string name;
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        string phone;
        float miles;
        static int orderCount;

    protected:
        float balance;

    public:
        const static float taxRate;
        const static float deliveryRate;
        DeliveryOrder(string, int, int, int, string, float, float);
        ~DeliveryOrder();
        void printReceipt() const;
        float calcBalance();
        float getBalance() const;
        static int getOrderCount();
        virtual float VIPdiscount() const = 0;
};

class BobaOrder : public DeliveryOrder 
{
    private:
        string shopName;
        static int drinksCount;

    public:
        BobaOrder(string, int, int, int, string, float, string, float);
        ~BobaOrder();
        void printReceipt() const;
        virtual float VIPdiscount() const;
        void addDrink(string, int, bool);
};

class FoodOrder : public DeliveryOrder
{
    private:
        string restaurantName;
        static int foodCount;

    public:
        
        FoodOrder(string, int, int, int, string, float, string, float);
        ~FoodOrder();
        void printReceipt() const;
        virtual float VIPdiscount() const;
        void addFood(string, int, bool);
};

class Account 
{
    private: 
        string username;
        string status;

    public:
        Account(string username, string status);
        ~Account();
        string getStatus() const;
};

class InvalidInput
{
    private:
        string message;
    
    public:
        InvalidInput(string s) : message("Invalid input [" + s + "].\n")
        {};
        
        void cause() {cout << message;}
};

float applyDiscount(DeliveryOrder*, Account const*);

#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a debugger may be new to you, but it will save you LOTS of time.

Running your program in a debugger would have shown you that your problem is here.

```
void FoodOrder::printReceipt() const
{
    FoodOrder::printReceipt();
    cout << "\tOrdered Foods: " << foodCount << endl;
}
```

Calling `FoodOrder::printReceipt()` will call `FoodOrder::printReceipt()`.  Infinitely.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be sure to get more familiar with using debuggers!